# How to use result of division in where inside MySQL query?

Tags: mysql

I've following database:

```
id  name prime product
1   x    2     2
2   z    3     6
3   y    17    102
4   d    5     30
5   a    7     210
6   b    11    330
7   c    13    390
```

Prime and product are used to determine ancestor. Now I need to find all ancestors of C which would work like this:

```
c.product / c.prime -> 390 / 13 = 30 --> ancestor D's product
d.product / d.prime -> 30 / 5 = 6 --> ancestor Z's product
z.product / z.prime -> 6 / 3 = 2 --> ancestor X's product
no more ancestors
```

Now my question is how to get the result of `C` and all it's ancestors within one simple MySQL query. This is the desired output:

```
id  name prime product
1   x    2     2
2   z    3     6
4   d    5     30
7   c    13    390
```

Anyone can give me a hint?

My current attempt is:

```
SELECT *, (product DIV prime) AS ancestor FROM temp.test_tree WHERE product = ancestor;
```

But that obviously doens't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM test_tree WHERE product IN (SELECT (product DIV prime) FROM test_tree ));
```

Comment: Thanks, that's almost perfect but I don't get C itself?

Comment: I wanted it little generic. as name 'a' (210/7), 'b'(330/11) are also 30. So ignored 'c'.

Comment: So there's including either a,b,c or none? But not c only?

Comment: As good working as your query is, I cannot turn it into a query that also include C. I should definitely freshen up my MySQL :(

Comment: To include 'c', try this `SELECT * FROM test_tree WHERE name = 'c' OR product IN (SELECT (product DIV prime) FROM test_tree )) ;`

Comment: Well, haha. I thought way too complicated there :D Once again, thank you!